# How to implement manual Facebook login in Xamarin.iOS using webview

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in my Xamarin.iOS application. I have tried to use Xamarin.Auth package,  but sometimes user cannot processed and there are some issues with this package. I found the best way is to implement manual login flow to my application (using web-view). Currently, I have created an app in Faceboook developer portal, and I can access the link from my iOS application.

So, user will click normal button which will be forwarded to Facebook login page. My question is, how can I get the result from Facebook login page? and how can I get user id, email, ... ?

Here is the source code so far:

```
partial void BtnFacebookLogin_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        NSUrl apiRequest =
            new NSUrl("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            + SharedResources.fbClientId
            + "&response_type=token&redirect_uri="
            + SharedResources.fbRedirectUrl);

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(apiRequest);
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use the official Facebook iOS API, Xamarin has a nuget/package that binds the native SDK https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.iOS/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried to implement FB login using their official SDK. But unfortunately, there is no sample or guide to do that. If you have any sample for implementing FB login by using their official SDK, I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Sample code: https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/tree/master/Facebook.iOS/samples

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I'll post the answer here soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by using Facebook SDK, which is currently considered as the best existing solution, after your download the official SDK (Xamarin.Facebook.iOS), here are the steps:

1. In Info.plist file, add these codes:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
      <key>facebook.com</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
      <key>fbcdn.net</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
      <key>akamaihd.net</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
```

2. Also in Info.plist file, the original view, Advanced tab, URL Types, add your facebook app ID like this way "fb1112222......". Keep 'fb' at the beginning.

[Pic: Facebook app ID in Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5xv6.png)

3. In AppDelegate.cs, override these methods:

   ```
       public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
       {
           // Override point for customization after application launch.
           // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

           Profile.EnableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true);
           Settings.AppID = "fb app id";
           Settings.DisplayName = "fb app name";

           // This method verifies if you have been logged into the app before, and keep you logged in after you reopen or kill your app.
           return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

           //return true;
       }

       public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
       {
           // We need to handle URLs by passing them to their own OpenUrl in order to make the SSO authentication works.
           return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
       }
   ```
4. Lastly, this is the function for Facebook, you can use their own button, or use your button. In my way, I used my button with the name (BtnFacebookLogin).

   //Here is the facebook function

   private void SetupFacebookLoginButton()
           {
               List readPermissions = new List { "public_profile", "email" };

   ```
           ////Set Up Button Design
           var fbBtnText = new NSAttributedString("login with facebook", new
               UIStringAttributes()
           {
               ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
           });


           BtnFacebookLogin.SetAttributedTitle(fbBtnText, UIControlState.Normal);
           BtnFacebookLogin.SetBackgroundImage(
               UIImage.FromBundle("btn_long_blue.png"), UIControlState.Normal);

           //Strat Login Functions
           Profile.Notifications.ObserveDidChange((sender, e) =>
           {
               if (e.NewProfile == null)
                   return;

               if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
               {
                   var request = new GraphRequest("/me?fields=name,email", null, AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString, null, "GET");
                   request.Start((connection, result, error) =>
                   {
                       // Handle if something went wrong with the request
                       if (error != null)
                       {
                           showAlert("Error", error.Description);
                           return;
                       }

                       fbReponseFromSDK facebookSDKLoginItem = new fbReponseFromSDK();
                       // Get your profile name
                       var userInfo = result as NSDictionary;
                       if(userInfo["id"] != null)
                       { 
                           Console.WriteLine("id is: " + userInfo["id"].ToString());
                       }
                       if (userInfo["name"] != null)
                       { 
                           Console.WriteLine("name is: " + userInfo["name"].ToString());
                       }
                       if (userInfo["email"] != null)
                       { 
                           Console.WriteLine("email is: " + userInfo["email"].ToString());
                       }
                      //(Success) Do what you want next :
                       doneFacbookLogin();
                   });
               }
           });

           // Handle actions once the user is logged in
           BtnFacebookLogin.ReadPermissions = readPermissions.ToArray();
           BtnFacebookLogin.Completed += (sender, e) =>
           {
               if (e.Error != null)
               {
                   // Handle if there was an error
                   showAlert("Facebook Login", e.Error.Description);
                   return;
               }

               if (e.Result.IsCancelled)
               {
                   // Handle if the user cancelled the login request
                   //showAlert("Facebook Login", "Login Cancelled");
                   return;
               }

               showAlert("Facebook Login", "Login Successfull");
           };

           // Handle actions once the user is logged out
           BtnFacebookLogin.LoggedOut += (sender, e) =>
           {
               // Handle your logout
           };

           // If you have been logged into the app before, ask for the your profile name
           if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
           {
               var request = new GraphRequest("/me?fields=name,email", null, AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString, null, "GET");
               request.Start((connection, result, error) =>
               {
                   // Handle if something went wrong with the request
                   if (error != null)
                   {
                       showAlert("Error", error.Description);
                       return;
                   }

                   // Get your profile name

               });
           }
       }
   ```

For more info, refere to their samples in GitHub ([Link](https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/tree/master/Facebook.iOS/samples))